# How to say "never mind" in German

Tags: english-to-german

How can I say "never mind" in German? For instance:

> I'm sorry, I lost that wallet you gave me. - **Never mind**, I can buy you another one.

Comment: Was sagt das Wörterbuch? Ach egal, ich schreib dir eine Antwort hin...

Comment: Ich sehe, dass man hier Fragen jedweder Art stellen kann, wie z.B. "By the way" was ebenfalls im Wörterbuch vorhanden ist.  P.S. Die Anspielung habe ich erst im Nachhinein eingesehen

Comment: (Sie war auch gut versteckt...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Man sagt zum Beispiel:

> Macht nix, ich kann...
>
> Egal, ich kann...
>
> Wurscht, ich kann...
>
> Mach dir nix draus, ich kann...
>
> Na ja, so was kommt vor. Ich kann...

in der Umgangssprache oder

> Macht nichts, ich kann...
>
> Das spielt keine Rolle, ich kann...
>
> Nicht so schlimm, ich kann...
>
> Mach dir nichts daraus, ich kann...
>
> Nicht so schlimm, ich kann...

in mehr standardsprachlicher Ausdrucksweise.

Mit etwas anderem Bedeutungsakzent (nämlich: "Nun verlier über so eine Kleinigkeit doch nicht so viele Worte!") hört man auch:

> Papperlapapp, ich kann...
>
> Ach was, ich kann...